# Python. Matplotlib. How to convert axes of a matrix to coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, coordinates, axes

it is the first time I ask in this portal, so I apologize if I did something wrong.

I have three lists that represent the coordinates x, y, z as follows:

X_grid = [[], [], ..., []]

Y_grid = [[], [], ..., []]

Z_grid = [[], [], ..., []]

I have a NODATA_value value defined, which is inside the Z_grid list, for points where I do not have a dimension value.

The problem is that I can not modify the x, y axes of the graph so that instead of indicating the value of the position of the element in the matrix, these indicate the coordinates x, y.

It is important that each point is drawn as a square, not as a rectangle, since they represent pixels.

I attach the code that I have right now. I would really appreciate it if someone gave me a hand in this.

[current result] https://ibb.co/kyzCtBK

```py
def visualizar_grid(X_grid, Y_grid, Z_grid, NODATA_value, name_DTM):
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    grid = Z_grid
    for i in range(len(Z_grid)):
        for j in range(len(Z_grid[0])):
            if Z_grid[i][j] == NODATA_value:
                grid[i][j] = grid[i][j]*np.nan

    plt.matshow(grid[::-1], cmap = 'jet')
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

    plt.colorbar()
    plt.grid()
    plt.title(name_DTM)
    image = plt.show()

    return image
```

Comment: Possibly you are looking for `imshow`'s `extent` keyword argument.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but I think that path is not the right one, or at least the shortest one.

Comment: Mhh, not sure what makes you think that way. But if you have any indication for `extent` not to be the best/correct way to manipulate the data range of an image, feel free to provide further details.